# properties of a Köthe space s

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Could you please help me answering the following question?

Consider the Köthe space $K_ {\infty}(n^p) = \{ x= (x_n)_1^{\infty}: |x|_p
:= \sup_n|x_n|n^p<\infty, \forall p \in \mathbb{N} \}$ with the topology
given by the norms $(|.|_p)_{p=1}^{\infty}$.

Show that $K_ {\infty}(n^p)$ is a Montel space, and the set $\{
exp(-log^{\beta}n))_{n=1}^{\infty}, 2<\beta<\infty \}$ is precompact but
$\{ exp(-log^{\beta}n))_{n=1}^{\infty}, 1<\beta<2 \}$ is not.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean be $\log^\beta n$? Is it $(\log(n))^\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $s$ of rapidely decreasing sequences is in fact a *Schwartz space* (it is even nuclear but this is not important for your question), i.e. the inclusions
$(s,|\cdot|_{p+1}|) \hookrightarrow (s,|\cdot|_p)$ map the unit ball of the former space to a precompact set of the latter. This comes from the observation that the quotients of weights $n^p$ converge to $0$. Using this you get that bounded sets in $s$ are precompact and, since $s$ is completely metrizable, they are relatively compact.

To check precompactness of a set $B$ you just need boundedness, i.e., $\sup\lbrace |x|_p: x\in B \rbrace <\infty$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain it more explicitly?